# MongoDB wiredTiger Error: collection-*.wt does not appear to be a WiredTiger file (Window10)

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

mongoDB version: 3.4.2 os: win10
Question: Cannot start mongoDB due to .wt file corruption
When reset mongoDB database path, cmd give the error as in picture
Any hint would be appreciated, thanks[image]

Comment: How you are starting the "mongod" server? And what is your installation location of mongodb "BIN" directory?

Comment: I open an cmd window under this path 'E:\Work_App\MongoDB\bin' and my installation of mongodb 'BIN' directory is 'E:\Work_App\MongoDB'. This step is aimed to reset the mongodb's db path to recover the mongodb to restart again(which normally works but this time fails).

Comment: Could you update the "BIN" folder (.exe) files like such as (mongod.exe (For server) & mongo (mongo shell) is there or not.

Comment: Are you sure this is your installation path of MongoDB "E:\Work_App_MongoDB\bin"(mongod server path). By default mongodb installation path is "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin". AS I am able to see from your screen shot no "server" folder is there.May be from wrong location you are trying to start the "mongod" server.

Comment: Yes, I install my mongodb in the above path ,not in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin. and my mongo and mongodb is in the path. Do you mean I need to update my mongo.exe and mongod.exe to the lastest version? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lizhen, may be Wiredtiger does unclean shutdown. Just go to 'E:\Work_App\MongoDB\bin' and type in command prompt like

Then run the query in command prompt `“mongod --dbpath /data/db –repair”`

**Suppose that** i have installed **MongoDB** in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin` then the query statement will be like that

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

As you already said your MongoDB installation path is `E:\Work_App_MongoDB\bin`. So in your place it would be

```
E:\Work_App_MongoDB\bin>mongod --dbpath /data/db –repair
```

I hope so that it will be help out to you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this method,but still not solve my problem. It seems to be collection corruption.